# How to evaluate the performance of DPDK in a complex circumstance

Tags: networking, dpdk

Let's think about a circumstance like that:

In a MMORPG Game, We send a packet to server, and the server will do a lot of computing about all the palyers who have some connection like attack or heal or somethingelse. After that, we may receive several packets.

Since we may receive several packets, the thing is a little hard. If we only read one, then we can just use timestamp to see the time cost. But now, we cannot do that. So, how to evaluate the performance between traditional TCP/IP stack and the DPDK process in a complex circumstance like that?

Comment: have tried the same with rx_burst with `n` set to `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`If we only read one, then we can just use timestamp to see the time cost. But now, we cannot do that.`
Answer> you can always register callback handler in RX, to get it invoked per packet.

`how to evaluate the performance between traditional TCP/IP stack and the DPDK process in a complex circumstance like that?`
Answer> I assume you are having TLDK or mTCP or ANS as userspace stack, your best approach is to have callback at each read success.